# ¿Como puedo enviar mensajes a 2 agentes simultáneamente con JADE?

Tags: java, jade, inteligencia-artificial

```
    public void action(){

        //MENSAJE PARA AGENTE 2
        AID id = new AID();
        id.setLocalName("Agente2");  //Receptor

        ACLMessage mensaje = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.REQUEST); 
        mensaje.setSender(getAID()); //Emisor
        mensaje.addReceiver(id);            
        mensaje.setContent("Hola Agente2");
        mensaje.setConversationId("cod2");
        mensaje.setLanguage("Latin");
        getAgent().send(mensaje);

        //PARA EL AGENTE 3
        AID id2 = new AID();
        id2.setLocalName("Agente3");  //Receptor
        ACLMessage mensaje2 = new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.REQUEST); 
        mensaje2.setSender(getAID()); //Emisor
        mensaje2.addReceiver(id2);
        mensaje2.setContent("Hola Agente3");
        mensaje2.setConversationId("cod3");
        mensaje2.setLanguage("Latin");
        getAgent().send(mensaje2);

        //RECIBE EL MENSAJE DE LOS DOS AGENTES
        ACLMessage mensajeRec = blockingReceive();
        System.out.println(mensajeRec.getContent());

    }
```

Comment: Has intentado hacer algo? comparte tu código para poder ayudarte

Comment: [Sin código, es difícil ayudarte](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2875/)